# Is it wrong to use HTML and PHP in this way?

Tags: php, html

I had document addsite.php like below.

```
<?php 
session_start();

if(condition){

///Include this document

include_once('sub_docs/addsite.php');

}
else {

die(header("author"));

exit();

}
?>
```

And my addsite.php in sub_docs is an combo of both HTML and PHP as below

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
....
....
<?php

?>

....
....

</html>
```

Everything is working fine in my local server but when went for production it is just showing the blank page. Not even a single markup tag. It is even entering the conditions and just stopping there. Neither of the die or include_once are working. There is no problem with any sql statements or the php script in between the html. I can't find the mistake. Please help.

Comment: is that header meant to be a redirect? if so you would use.

header ("location: http://example.com")

Comment: Usually when you have a totally blank output on a production server this means that there has been a PHP error. Look at the server logs or enable error_reporting in php.ini

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try turning on some error reporting so you can see what's happening:

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

Also - make sure your secondary page is a .php file and not an .html, unless of course you have it setup in your .htaccess file to allow .html to run as php.